# WebApplication can't access wcf service deployed on same machine

Tags: iis-10

We have a WebApp & WCF service running under AppPools A1(using service account User1) & A2(using service account User2) respectively.
While webapp is trying to connect to wcf service, we are getting following error System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond

The only way I can make webapplication access the wcf service is if I'm logged in to the web server using the service account User2.
Once the service account user logs off the server, the same error appears.

Here is the web server/app configuration
.NET version : v 4.0 
IIS : 10.0.14393.0
OS : Windows Server 2016

Comment: Both are Windows authentication? Check Kerberos delegation.

Comment: Yes, the service accounts are from AD